# How to iterate over pattern matches?

Tags: vimscript

I've got a file, containing some output log.
It consists of several blocks of information, that start and end with some fixed patterns.

I need to put a summary for each block in the beginning of the file.

Additionally, I'd like to study vim scripting.

I've developed a couple of functions: one of them processes line range and returns a string with the summary, and another one puts this string in the first line of a file.

```
function! GetBlockSummary(first, last)
    " some text processing
endfunction

function! ProcessBlock() range
    let summary = GetBlockSummary(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    call append(0, summary)
endfunction
```

Then I call them: `:/startpattern/;/endpattern/ call ProcessBlock()`

Now I've got two problems:

1. There are many blocks in the file, and it is tedious to repeat the command by hands. This can be solved with putting the call into a macro and then calling that macro with count prefix (say, `90@q`, if I have known that there are 90 blocks in the file, and have put the call into the `@q` register)
2. But different files have different amount of blocks, and I have to call `grep` to count them.

So, I'm looking for some `while` loop example, implementing following pattern:

```
while /startpattern/ is found
    execute :/startpattern/;/endpattern/ call ProcessBlock()
endwile
```

Here is the example.

Original file:

```
start/weights-e55_ta0.98_va0.96.ckpt
Extracting frames 
Using precomputed keys
Done, 1247 frames
acc1 1
acc2 2
acc3 3
acc4 5
end
start/weights-e18_ta0.84_va0.12.ckpt
Extracting frames 
Using precomputed keys
Done, 1247 frames
acc1 5
acc2 2
acc3 3
acc4 4
end
```

Each block starts from `start/....` and ends with `end`. Numbers after "e" in `weights-e...` denote block numbers.

For this example I'd like to have this file prepended with block numbers and `acc`'s that equal 5. It is guaranteed that only one `acc\d 5` appears in the block:

```
Block 55: acc4
Block 18: acc1
start/weights-e55_ta0.98_va0.96.ckpt
Extracting frames 
Using precomputed keys
.... the rest of text
```

Comment: example of the file you are processing and the result you want to get would be really good to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach, using `:h global` command:

```
:g/startpattern/.;/endpattern/ call ProcessBlock
```

1. `:g/startpattern/` search for `startpattern`
2. `.;/endpattern/call ProcessBlock` when found, use range from current line to `endpattern` and call your function. (it should be defined with range)

**ADD**

```
function! ProcessBlock() range
    " get block number
    let block = matchstr(getline(a:firstline), '-e\zs\d\d')
    " get acc 5
    let acc = ''
    for linenr in range(a:firstline+1, a:lastline)
        let line = getline(linenr)
        if line =~ 'acc\d 5'
            let acc = matchstr(line, 'acc\d')
            break
        endif
    endfor
    call append(0, printf("Block %s: %s", block, acc))
endfunction
```

```
g/start/.;/end/call ProcessBlock()
```

**PS**

[image]

Comment: Wow! How do you make vim process function?

Comment: my plugin https://github.com/habamax/vim-evalvim

Comment: And you can do it without a plugin of course, I have just added convenience.

Comment: And a cherry on a top - sort all summaries by block numbers: `nnoremap <F9> :g/start/.;/end/ call ProcessBlock()<CR>gg:.,/start/-1 sort n<cr>`

Comment: no need to `gg`, just use range starting from line 1, smth like `:1,/start/-1 sort n<CR>`

Comment: I need :). Because I want to see these summaries